# Position an html5 video element to fit into custom graphics

Tags: css, html, video, background-image, positioning

I have drawn an outline of a mobile phone. I need to fit some short video clips into the screen of the phone. How would you go about it?

The drawn screen and video ratio are the same. It needs to be responsive of course, so my video has to scale with the frame (the graphics). Because of the graphics it is not as simple as placing the video element in a container. I was trying to achieve it first with the phone as a background image. Now I'm thinking of two absolutely positioned elements (phone and video) overlapping each other. Maybe a div containing the video and an absolutely positioned pseudo element ::after holding the graphics?

I often make simple things complex, so please kindly advise if there is a better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're applying your drawn frame as a background image here?

You'll definitely have to nest two divs to get the positioning correct, but rather than applying absolute positioning to both you're better off using `object:fit` on the video container to nest it into the provided space. This way you only need to set your formatting on the drawn frame and CSS will take care of the video formatting.

There's a good breakdown and demo of this [here](https://wesbos.com/css-object-fit/).

Keep in mind (as with all things), there are compatibility issues with IE. Everything else is compatible, though.

Comment: Well, yes `object:fit` is a nice declaration. The problem here however is to perfectly match the drawn frame to the video container and keep it together during scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it, although I still think it is not a good solution. The problem was to perfectly match the video container with drawn frame. I did that by adding the graphic frame as an absolutely positioned pseudo element `:after` to the video container. The pseudo element (mobile phone drawing) is proportionally scaled up to contain the video exactly where the phone screen is supposed to be.
Html:

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
      <div class="clip-container">
        <video loop muted autoplay poster="" >
          <source src="img/my_clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.clip-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.clip-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-image: url(../img/iphone_stroke.svg);
  z-index: 1000;
  left: -18%;
  bottom: -18%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 135%; /* Relative size of the graphics to contain the video */
  height: 135%;
}
```

Unfortunately I needed to know exactly in percentages how big the drawn phone needed to be to contain the video. Therefore I do not think this is the optimal and clean solution. Still hoping for better ideas.